# Do we require Oracle 11g Client if we are using SQL Developer?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Do we require to install Oracle client on local machine if we are using SQL Developer(local machine) for accessing the oracle database on the server(different from local)?

Comment: SQL Developer includes the database access drivers it needs to connect to the database.

Comment: So.. we don't require it right?

Answer (score 1):

We don't require to install Oracle 11g client if we want to access the Oracle database which is present on different machine or server. We just require the tool for accessing the same. For example, SQL Developer. Also we require the credentials such as username, password, hostname, sid, port no.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes yes. For example when your account expires, then there is no way how to change your password via JDBC. This is Oracle specific feature, there it is not supported by JDBC standard.

When DBA creates you account with expiring password, and your password expires, then you have no other way then connecting via OCI to resolve this.
JDBC does not allow you to open a session using two passwords(old one and a now one).

Also errors messages from OCI drivers contain more information then JDBC ones.

Comment: But, the account reactivation feature access is only with admin and I am not having any rights for the same... so...then we don't require right?